# How to enforce constraints in NMinimize

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am trying to minimize a function `EtotalEM[R,Δ]` that is defined only for `Δ <= R/ ArcSinh[1]` (approximately: `Δ <= 1.15 R`). I therefore try to set constraints that enforce this condition. It shouldn't matter at this point how exactly `EtotalEM` is defined. Here is the syntax for minimization, including the constraints:

```
NMinimize[{10^18 EtotalEM[10^-9 R, 10^-9 Δ], 
   {Δ <= R/ ArcSinh[1], Δ > 0, Δ < 100, R > 5, R < 10^4}},
   {Δ, R}
```

The numbers of `10^18` and `10^-9` are there to bring the variables close to one. The puzzling thing for me is now that I get an error

`NMinimize::nrnum: The function value 1084.22 -1.2459 I is not a real number at {R,Δ} = {5.0692,34.3423}.`

I don't understand why this should be a problem for NMinimize because I explicitly excluded the combination `{R,Δ} = {5.0692,34.3423}`. Apparently, my constraints are ignored. What is going wrong?

Edit: I found a simple example that demonstrates the issue:

```
NMinimize[{(1/Sqrt[x - y] Exp[x]) (1/y Exp[y]),
   {x > y, y > 0, x < 10000, x > 0}}, {x, y}]
```

fails with

```
NMinimize::nrnum: The function value 1.62712 -3.76001 I is not a real number at {x,y} = {0.069203,0.727035}.
```

If I omit the `x>0` constraint (which is actually redundant since `x>y` and `y>0` is already required), then the error message is

```
NMinimize::nrnum: The function value 312498. -4.15812*10^-244 I is not a real number at {x,y} = {-558.288,0.727042}.
```

In both cases, the actual result of the NMinimize command is some nonsense like `x -> 860.974` instead of `x -> 1`. Also worth noting, without the last two constraints, the command completes without error messages and yields the correct result.

Comment: I understand, that you want to keep your EtotalEM-funciton secret, but it would help to determine whats wrong there. Can you produce another, perhaps similar, function where the same happens?

Comment: Yes, please see the edits.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42999/nminimize-go-out-of-bounds-on-some-linear-constraints...There are other related Q&A, too, I think.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`NMinimize` tries to enforce constraints by adding a penalty function to the objective function (see [Why does NMaximize does not follow the constraints that were given to it?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69622/why-does-nmaximize-does-not-follow-the-constraints-that-were-given-to-it/69644#69644)). So it doesn't strictly observe the constraints in its search for the minimum.  One workaround is to use `Piecewise` to give a pretty high value outside the domain.

```
 obj[x_, y_] := 
  Piecewise[{{(1/Sqrt[x - y] Exp[x]) (1/y Exp[y]), 
     And @@ {x > y, y > 0, x < 10000, x > 0}}},
   Exp[10000]
   ];
 NMinimize[{obj[x, y], {x > y, y > 0, x < 10000, x > 0}}, {x, y}]
 (*  {12.6761, {x -> 1., y -> 0.5}}  *)
```

Comment: Yes, it now converges to the correct result without error messages, however at a super slow speed (which becomes apparent when using a more costly function). To check, see `ListPlot[Last[
  Reap[NMinimize[{obj[x, y]}, {x, y}, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[x]]]]]` and compare to `ListPlot[Last[
  Reap[NMinimize[{(1/Sqrt[x - y] Exp[x]) (1/y Exp[y]), {x > y, 
      y > 0}}, {x, y}, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[x]]]]]`

Comment: Maybe this can be optimized by using the mysterious function "NonlinearInteriorPoint" instead of Exp[10000]. Unfortunately, I have no idea how  to use this function.

Comment: @Felix I think your two calls are using different methods.  Try passing the same method to each, such as `Method -> "NelderMead"`. I get what look like identical results.

Comment: Yes, indeed, with the method specified it gives both a good result. Thanks.

Comment: Is this the best that can be done? Seems pretty tedious...